# Android SoundPool plays, but audio is choppy. Any suggestions?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am working with `SoundPool`, the context is I want to play multiple sound effects in a loop.

All works fine except the fact that some effect's audio quality is too poor, and this happens randomly.

Hearing to those sound effects, it feels like audio is choppy and plays 2-3 times, I tried to alter the rate at which the effects play and initializing stream volume as in `SoundPool.play(index, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);` just 1 time to reduce the delay, but to no avail.

I also tried various audio formats like ogg, wav, mp3 but all is same.

Can someone be kind enough to shed some light on this.